# R, line chart appears as columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm a newbie in the R programming language and i wanted to make a line chart based on some values from a dataframe that goes like this:
DataFrame i'm using, changed year from vector to numerical

[image: DataFrame i'm using, changed year from vector to numerical]

The thing is that even after the code (pasting it next) that should work by using the ggplot plugin it does not make a historical line chart, but makes columns with all the variables grouped in the single years.

This is the code i used:

```
dc %>%
group_by(dc$year,dc$month)
ggplot(data=dc)+
geom_line(aes(x=year,y=sales),col="red",lwd=1)+
geom_point(aes(x=year,y=sales))
```

This should theoretically group the year and month variables together so that in the geom_line function the data i'm giving it should expand just like any other history line chart, but somehow, that's what i'm getting.

My result
[image: My result].

Is there something i wrote wrong or something i should have thinked about the grouping/something else?

Comment: Hello newbie like and welcome to SO! We try to avoid links to pictures or tables (hence the edit). Putting everything in the question itself makes it allot easier to follow and heightens the chance someone will answer it. 
Your code says you want to use Years as X and Sales as Y, as there are multiple sales per year it will stack them 'column-like' on your x-axis, your result fits with your data and syntax. If you want a clear line chart it will be necessary to have 1 y-value for each x-value. 
As your code and it's result are correct, this question could be closed as off topic.

Comment: so how would i go to make that ratio though? can i like, wrap it to multiple groups for each sales or something?

Comment: Please include your dataset in a reproducible form, i.e. output of `dput(dc[,c("year", "month", "sales")])` .  Grouping is not helpful here, at least not in that way; what you should be after is a proper set of values for x-axis, i.e. a date or just year and month combined.

Comment: That depends on what you want to show with your results. You can 'combine' your sales values to represent an average per year, change it to amount of sales (frequency per year) or total amount (cumulative number per year).  Or change the x-axis to represent months so you have a line chart.  :) you have many options with your dataset

Comment: I did try using the months as the x axis but they still gave me the same result, i also i'm updating with the dput for the values i need.

Comment: There are 240 rows, 4 sets of 5*12 months. Do You have 4 cities there and do you want to have a line for each? If yes, then sorry, the data sample should include `city` column as well,  i.e. `dput(dc[,c("city", "year", "month", "sales")])` . Or you can just provide all the data as it does not seem to be too large for SO:  `dput(dc)` . Please consider updating the question and description of desired output as well, currently there's no hint of multiple series.

Comment: My bad, updated again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start by creating a date column for x-axis (combine day and month to a string and parse those values with `lubridate::ym()`, stands for year-month). Then we'll set aesthetics for all layers.
As there are multiple data series, colour those by `city`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

dc %>%
  mutate(Period = paste(year, month, sep = "-") %>% ym()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Period, y = sales, color = city), alpha = .8) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Input data:

```r
dc <- structure(list(city = c("Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Beaumont", 
"Beaumont", "Beaumont", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", "Bryan-College Station", 
"Bryan-College Station", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", 
"Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls", "Wichita Falls"
), year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), month = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L), sales = c(83L, 108L, 182L, 200L, 202L, 189L, 164L, 174L, 
124L, 150L, 150L, 148L, 108L, 108L, 146L, 166L, 143L, 177L, 163L, 
160L, 127L, 155L, 124L, 151L, 110L, 135L, 175L, 176L, 197L, 173L, 
182L, 218L, 182L, 193L, 162L, 160L, 159L, 140L, 170L, 198L, 246L, 
232L, 206L, 273L, 213L, 188L, 177L, 212L, 148L, 186L, 182L, 208L, 
246L, 254L, 212L, 262L, 224L, 260L, 180L, 202L, 89L, 107L, 176L, 
233L, 282L, 286L, 189L, 196L, 122L, 100L, 101L, 130L, 94L, 101L, 
162L, 186L, 238L, 284L, 244L, 196L, 131L, 114L, 124L, 135L, 115L, 
124L, 149L, 193L, 294L, 293L, 292L, 296L, 149L, 163L, 159L, 134L, 
141L, 125L, 187L, 267L, 341L, 357L, 402L, 328L, 186L, 164L, 166L, 
190L, 152L, 171L, 275L, 303L, 353L, 377L, 403L, 298L, 204L, 218L, 
169L, 200L, 160L, 181L, 250L, 316L, 282L, 262L, 255L, 238L, 220L, 
202L, 155L, 209L, 143L, 181L, 241L, 253L, 271L, 313L, 278L, 295L, 
258L, 227L, 208L, 198L, 169L, 225L, 271L, 253L, 289L, 302L, 322L, 
317L, 281L, 289L, 210L, 234L, 197L, 227L, 298L, 289L, 326L, 335L, 
369L, 357L, 287L, 272L, 253L, 239L, 238L, 244L, 282L, 323L, 388L, 
423L, 371L, 347L, 361L, 369L, 300L, 332L, 89L, 91L, 147L, 167L, 
165L, 129L, 104L, 130L, 132L, 113L, 97L, 117L, 80L, 79L, 119L, 
111L, 128L, 111L, 127L, 135L, 113L, 98L, 93L, 81L, 105L, 90L, 
116L, 125L, 102L, 130L, 132L, 123L, 95L, 97L, 119L, 115L, 79L, 
101L, 159L, 124L, 144L, 121L, 150L, 149L, 128L, 114L, 94L, 92L, 
89L, 93L, 102L, 143L, 140L, 123L, 150L, 137L, 110L, 112L, 96L, 
109L)), row.names = c(NA, -240L), class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wow that finally works! So if i understand correctly, you created the "period" var that takes from the dc the year and month columns and fuses them together with the ym() function and then used that as a x value so that the graph would be a line chart?
So the only thing that made my original code non-functional was because the year alone wasn't accustomed to the sales value because sales was too big for all the cities to be grouped into?

Comment: Well, fusing together happens with just `paste()`,  resulting strings are passed to `ym()` that converts those to actual date values, ggplot will then use proper date scale on x-axis. Colouring (or grouping) by `city` is another key point here, feel feel to remove it and check the results.

Comment: oh i see, and if i wanted to break the x axis into each year i would do that with
scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(2010,2014,1)) or would it make stuff not work since the year/months are merged? Not that i'd mind if it didn't work, so thanks!

Comment: @NEWBIELIKE ,  you would first need to aggregate your data to have a single value per year for every city, i.e.  yearly mean or median media values or any other metric of choice; this usually takes place before ggplot, with a `group_by()` / `summarise()` step if Tidiverse happens to your preferred approach.

Answer (score 1):

so this solution assigns a new column where the dates are stored. It will use the first day of each month. In the plot the scale_x_date function lets me assign a pattern how these dates will be shown. As we do not want the days to be shown i just removed them.
Furthermore, if you use the aes function in the call of ggplot it will automatically pass it on to the geoms. And the pipe operator (%>%) will get your dataset into the ggplot function.

```
dc %>% mutate(ymonth = as_date(paste0(year,"-",month,"-",1))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=ymonth,y=sales))+
  geom_line(col="red",lwd=1)+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Tried this but it gave me an error:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `ymonth = as_date(paste0(year, "-", month, "-", 1))`.
Caused by error in `as_date()`:
! could not find function "as_date"

is "as_date" part of some other library?

Comment: `as_date` is from `lubridate`

Comment: I see, well, that's kinda better, but still makes the result similar to the original, just with groups based on the first month, maybe there's a way to make it go for each months and each year instad of just one month?